# SQL query find supplier with lowest price for each part

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to find the supplier with the lowest price for each part.

Tables: suppliers(sid, sname, address), parts(pid, pname, colour), catalog(sid, pid, cost)

This works:

```
SELECT 
    sname, pid
FROM
    (SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        suppliers
    NATURAL JOIN catalog
    NATURAL JOIN (SELECT 
        pid, MIN(cost) AS min_cost
    FROM
        catalog
    GROUP BY (pid)) AS m
    HAVING cost = min_cost) AS n
```

But when I try to shorten it to the following I get an error that there is an unknown cost in the having clause:

```
SELECT 
    sname, pid
FROM
    suppliers
        NATURAL JOIN
    catalog
        NATURAL JOIN
    (SELECT 
        pid, MIN(cost) AS min_cost
    FROM
        catalog
    GROUP BY (pid)) AS m
HAVING cost = min_cost
```

Why can't it find the cost? Isn't the cost in the table because I've joined the subquery to catalog?

**EDIT**

I changed it to use `INNER JOIN` instead of `NATURAL JOIN` as per suggestions, but I'm still getting the same error. New query:

```
SELECT 
    s.sname, m.pid
FROM
    suppliers s
        INNER JOIN
    catalog c ON s.sid = c.sid
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        pid, MIN(cost) AS min_cost
    FROM
        catalog
    GROUP BY (pid)) AS m ON c.pid = m.pid
HAVING cost = min_cost
```

**EDIT_2**

The problem was not the `JOIN` but the `HAVING`, which should actually be `WHERE`, as shown by bbrumm's answer.

Comment: Just forget `NATURAL JOIN`.  It is a bug waiting to happen (or actually happening, as in this case).  Use the `ON` or `USING` clauses.

Comment: @GordonLinoff that explains why I haven't seen it in any SO answers then. And why we always used `ON` in my VBA course when using Access databases. However, right now I'm in a beginner RDBMS course and our prof. has told us to use `NATURAL JOIN` whenever possible... good to know for the future though

Comment: Sounds like a prof. that does not want to answer questions.

Comment: Yeah, as Gordon said, avoid NATURAL JOIN where you can. NATURAL JOIN requires that both tables have the same column name which is not always the case. Using your JOIN statement (INNER JOIN, for example) is better, and you can specify the ON clause. If the professor is saying that NATURAL JOIN is better, I would question the reason for that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest a query like this:

```
SELECT
supplier.sname,
catalog.pid
FROM suppliers
INNER JOIN catalog ON suppliers.supplier_id = catalog.supplier_id 
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
     pid, MIN(cost) AS min_cost
    FROM catalog
    GROUP BY (pid)) AS m
ON catalog.pid = m.pid
WHERE catalog.cost = m.min_cost;
```

I've made a few assumptions on your column names (e.g. supplier_id) that you may need to change. A point could be made that the "cost=min_cost" is part of the JOIN so it could go there as well. I've also not included table aliases as while it's best practice, it's not required.

Comment: I just updated my question and I had the same query as yours, I just needed to change `HAVING` to `WHERE`. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. FYI - the HAVING performs a similar function to WHERE, but is usually used with GROUP BY clauses as it runs at a different point behind the scenes.